# sort a file by number of each line and insert it to another file

Tags: c#, file, sorting

I have the next file: `timesBetweenStartToEnd.txt` that contains:

```
Starting at: 12:15:28 -> Ending at: 12:17:38 -> 130 Seconds
Starting at: 12:12:18 -> Ending at: 12:12:38 -> 20 Seconds
.....
```

I want to sort it by the number of seconds and insert the sorted lines into another file is called: `logTimes.txt`.

I tried the next thing:

```
string[] scores = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("timesBetweenStartToEnd.txt");
var orderedScores = scores.OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Split(' ')[8]
.Substring(0,scores.IndexOf(" "))); // here I have an error because of `scores.`, I neead an index

foreach (var score in orderedScores)
{
     System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"logTimes.txt", string.Format("{0}{1}", orderedScores, Environment.NewLine));
}
```

so, `logTimes.txt` should contain (descending order):

```
Starting at: 12:15:28 -> Ending at: 12:17:38 -> 130 Seconds
Starting at: 12:12:18 -> Ending at: 12:12:38 -> 20 Seconds
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Try without `Substring(...)`

Comment: thank you but I got lines of: System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.String,System.Int32]

Comment: Also, based on your example of the output, don't you need to use rather ascending order?

Comment: so you need to sort based on your Seconds value?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to say that I want a Descending Order. and yes, I want to sort according to the seconds.. thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works efficiently if the format is strict:

```
var orderedLines = File.ReadLines("timesBetweenStartToEnd.txt")
    .Select(l =>
    {
        int secondsIndex = l.LastIndexOf(" -> ");
        int? sec = (int?)null;
        if(secondsIndex != -1)
        {
            secondsIndex += " -> ".Length;
            int secondEndIndex = l.IndexOf(" Seconds", secondsIndex);
            if (secondEndIndex != -1)
            {
                int length = secondEndIndex - secondsIndex;
                string secondsPart = l.Substring(secondsIndex, length).Trim();
                int seconds;
                if (int.TryParse(secondsPart, out seconds))
                    sec = (int?)seconds;
            }
        }
        return new { Line = l, Seconds = sec };
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Seconds)
    .Select(x => x.Line);
File.WriteAllLines("logTimes.txt", orderedLines);
```

Since i've selected a `Nullable<int>` you could simply add a `Where` if you only want to log valid lines:

```
...
.Where(x => x.Seconds.HasValue)
.OrderBy(x => x.Seconds.Value)
.Select(x => x.Line);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you try to refference the current array elemt that is processed by the lambda statement. But in your statement you don't use it, instead you use the whole array. change the line to:

```
var orderedScores = scores.OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Split(' ')[8]
.Substring(0,x.IndexOf(" ")));
```

Comment: x is the complete line, you cannot use that when processing the seconds part.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But this causes the error in his code. And seemingly this was what he wanted to do.

Comment: I think he could substitute the x.IndexOf(" ") part with a fixed number, because the front part is always the same length.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following correction:

```
string[] scores = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("timesBetweenStartToEnd.txt");
var orderedScores = scores.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(' ')[8].Split(' ')[0]));

foreach (var score in orderedScores)
{
     System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"logTimes.txt", string.Format("{0}{1}", score, Environment.NewLine));
}
```

Note, that this solution is sensitive to proper syntax and will throw you exceptions if any of the lines do not match your example lines.

Comment: I'm sorry but the lines in my new file are: System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.String,System.Int32]

Comment: It was caused by a trivial mistake in your code when you had "orderedScores" in your string.Format parameter instead of the "score" foreach variable. I've corrected the code, however, I don't quite understand how you did not manage to notice and correct that. It was easier to notice that than posting a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var orderedScores = scores.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf("->"),  
x.IndexOf("Seconds") - x.LastIndexOf("->")).Trim("-->".ToCharArray()).Trim()));
```

if you're arranging based on the seconds value at the end. this might help you

Comment: thank you but I got: System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.String,System.Int32]